# jquery hit counter

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I create a unique hit/click counter works on ip.

To display the number of clic, I use on the body tag the onload function.
For example:

```
<body class="homepage" onload="affiche_compteur('compteur1'); affiche_compteur('compteur2');affiche_compteur('compteur3');affiche_compteur('compteur4');affiche_compteur('compteur5');affiche_compteur('compteur6');">
```

affiche_compteur (in french)= display_counter

I need to call with onload each click counter present in my html page. (It works for hardcoded element, however in my case I have appended element on document ready that are not present in my html page (not hardcoded))

Is there a way to get every id of click counter to avoid to add each counter onload?

Here my ajax script :

```
function getXhr(){
    var xhr = null; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {         
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {   
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } else {
           alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest..."); 
           xhr = false; 
    } 
    return xhr;
};
function affiche_compteur(id_clics)
{
    var xhr = getXhr();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            document.getElementById(id_clics).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', './compteur/affiche_compteur.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('compteurId='+id_clics);
}
```

Here the html for clicked element:

```
<div class="element blog " id="_13">
<a class="link" href="/portfolio/dock.html" onclick="gestionClic('compteur13');">
</a>
</div>

<div class="element blog " id="_12">
<a class="link" href="/portfolio/dock.html" onclick="gestionClic('compteur12');">
</a>
</div>

<div class="element blog " id="_11">
<a class="link" href="/portfolio/dock.html" onclick="gestionClic('compteur11');">
</a>
</div>
```

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Comment: Just out of curiosity:  If you use jQuery, why do you roll your own XHR and don't use the jQuery `ajax()` implementation?

Comment: I don't know... I write like this to be able to read a php script. then to write incremented click number in a data base if the ip doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
           $(document).on('click','#'+id_clics,function(){
              gestionClic(id_clics);
           });
         document.getElementById(id_clics).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This script is just for display the click counter. In your code you get just the click count id number 13. I want to search every id number click counter without click on an element. Actually, I put in the body an onload function and write each id counter to display them.

Comment: Ok but there is the click problem. I want to get the click number without any click. My click number are store in a file. Maybe with a find? I already have an other script that increment click and then display it after click.